sqlplus column header misaligned
In wide sqlplus reports, column headers get misaligned from the data

The code that led to this output was:
set linesize 32767
set trimspool on

col z format a1

alter session set nls_date_format='yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss';

pro....+....1....+....2....+....3....+....4....+....5....+....6....+....7....+....8....+....9....+....0....+....1....+....2....+....3
select sysdate a, sysdate b, sysdate c, sysdate d, sysdate e, 'yyyyyyyyyyy' y, 'z' z from dual;

select sysdate a, sysdate b, sysdate c, sysdate d, sysdate e, sysdate f, 'z' z from dual;

How can this be fixed?

set tab off

fixes the problem.
